# How to dynamically add items into array and count their occurrence?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I get a butt ton of automated alerts for this one thing (500-600 a day) and I'm trying to write a powershell script to analyze them for me.

What it can do right now is

1. Parse a subfolder in my outlook
2. Using regex, automatically grabs a specific variable in the email alert
3. Every loop dumps every match into a new line on a csv

I'm trying to count the occurrence of each user. So if "jdoe" comes along, it adds it to an array. And if "Jdoe" shows up 4 more times over the course of 2000 or so emails, then at the end it'll say something like

> Jdoe    5
>
> Jbond   2
>
> Guest   100

I was thinking possibly a two dimensional array? But I can't wrap my head around it.

I'm a pretty weak coder, what I have below I've had to comment so I can better understand exactly what each piece is doing

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$DebugPreference = 'Continue'

#------------
# Selects my Inbox, and then selects sub-folder under inbox. For my outlook, I have a subfolder called
# "Account Locked Alerts" that I have an outlook rule put all of the account locked out alerts in
#------------
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)    
$subfolder = $inbox.Folders('Account Locked Alerts')

#------------
#I'm using RegEx here because selecting the values is super dooper easy. Also, there's technically two "account name" value in these emails
# and I'm interested in the second.
#------------
$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Account Name\s*:\s*(?<AccName>.*?)$.*Account Name\s*:\s*(?<Acc2Name>.*?)$.*'

$users = @()


#------------
# For every email in my sub folder...
# (p.s., to check every email in "inbox", just replace $subfolder with $inbox)
#------------
$Data = ForEach ($item in $subfolder.items){

    #------------
    # Check to see if there's a match, and if there is....
    #------------
    if ($item.body -match $RE){
        #------------
        # Add to array and write it to csv
        #------------
        Write-Host "ding " $Matches.Acc2Name
        $users += $Matches.Acc2name
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                AccName = $Matches.Acc2Name
            }
    }

}


$Data 
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

EDIT: This question has been flagged as a dup as another. I don't believe so, because the linked possible dup already knows what variables to expect, and just counts them. I have 9000 variables that I don't know, with users coming and going by the hundreds every week. It's the dynamically adding and THEN counting, though the "possible duplicate" answers half of my question.

Comment: You don't need the `$users` variable if you are going to store the results in the `$Data` variable. I would for starters remove the `$users += ` from your loop.

Comment: Gotcha, so my results are already in data. I just need to figure out how to count each occurrence then. Thank you I'll see what I can do.

Comment: You can use `$Data | Group-Object AccName`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count occurence of data in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36333707/count-occurence-of-data-in-array)

Comment: @LotPings, I don't think so. I found quite a bit of examples like that, but a lot of them use expected results, for example, the one you linked the solution assumed you knew what variables were going to occur. I have about 9000 users that lock out their accounts all the time, with users in the hundreds comming and going weekly.

Comment: @Ghawblin - The fixed set of variables in the linked question is to easy test the answer but you can add key's to hash tables on the fly without any special logic. It would work too.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers gotcha, I'll give it a go.

Thank you for your help and input on this, I really appreciate it and hope you have a good day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some minor issues with your script. The `$users` variable is not needed and you can use `group-by` to get the results you are after.

Following slightly altered script might be all thats needed.

```
#------------
#I'm using RegEx here because selecting the values is super dooper easy. Also, there's technically two "account name" value in these emails
# and I'm interested in the second.
#------------
$RE = [RegEx]'(?sm)Account Name\s*:\s*(?<AccName>.*?)$.*Account Name\s*:\s*(?<Acc2Name>.*?)$.*'


#------------
# For every email in my sub folder...
# (p.s., to check every email in "inbox", just replace $subfolder with $inbox)
#------------
$Data = ForEach ($item in $subfolder.items){

    #------------
    # Check to see if there's a match, and if there is....
    #------------
    if ($item.body -match $RE){
        #------------
        # Add to array and write it to csv
        #------------
        Write-Verbose "ding " $Matches.Acc2Name
        [PSCustomObject]@{
                Acc2Name = $Matches.Acc2Name
        }
    }

}

$Data | Group-Object -Property Acc2Name -NoElement
$Data | Export-CSv '.\data.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: If just the count is of interrest, IMO incrementing hash table entries is more efficient than first gathering dupes and counting them, like the accepted answer in my proposed duplicate does.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Running with that produces: 

DEBUG: "Sort-Object" - "Acc2Name" cannot be found in "InputObject".

Changing:

$Data | Group-Object -Property Acc2Name -NoElement

to

$Data | Group-Object -Property $Matches.Acc2Name -NoElement

Produces

" cannot be found in "InputObject".

I'm about to read up on Group-Object. I've also learned that comments don't preserve line breaks. Owch.

Comment: @LotPings - I was thinking the same but it should not matter much for ~2000 matches/day.

Comment: @Ghawblin - I fixed a typo in the Group-Object line.

Comment: No you were correct the first time, Acc2Name is the proper variable. The first AccName in my alerts are the PC name, the second AccName is the user. You've given me a good area to start at though. Thank you!